# End of line ^M character on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, character-encoding, adobe-brackets

I have been working on a project for a while using git. I always use Brackets, usually on Ubuntu but some times also on Windows. The point is that now, on Ubuntu, when I try to submit some changes to my project, I see it added ^M at the end of each modified line.

If I'm not wrong, this is the end of line character for Windows. This is why it puzzles me: why is Ubuntu adding it? And the most important question, what can I do to get rid of them?

I tried different text editors without luck.

[image: Screenshot of the ^M character on Ubuntu]

Comment: I guess, it's your text editor. Fix it

Comment: Many text editors on Unix will add `^M` when you are editing a file that already contains Windows-style endings (and I would argue that this is the correct thing to do). Are you editing files that were originally created on Windows?

Comment: @Chris it's possible, yes. but then, any advice on how to avoid text editors to add ^M? I searched all the options and I didn't find anything...

Comment: @Aljullu, simply configure your editor to use Unix line endings by default on all platforms. Existing files will not (probably) be converted automatically, but your editor may be able to do this for you. If not, a tool like `dos2unix` can.

Comment: @Chris finally I used dos2unix, thank you!

Comment: The Linux/UNIX end-of-line character is LF (`'\n'`, character 10). The Windows end-of-line sequence is two characters, CR-LF (`"\r\n"`, characters 13 and 10). A Windows-style line ending, when viewed by something that assumes UNIX line endings, will look like a ^M (CR) character at the end of a line; the second character of the Windows-style end-of-line sequence matches the UNIX-style end-of-line character.

Answer (score 3):

The `^M` is the carriage return character. You are seeing this because you are looking at a file in Unix that was created in DOS (Windows). In DOS the `end-of-line` is composed of a Carriage Return (CR) (ASCII 13, `\r`) and a Line Feed (ASCII 10, `\n`) (LF), this is known as CR-LF `\r\n`. In Unix, the `end-of-line` is marked by a single newline `\n`. This is why you get the carriage-return `^M` right before the end-of-line since that is the way how `\r` is displayed in Unix. You can fix this with Vim.

Open your file with Vim

```
Vim <file_name>
```

with *:e* you will reload the file in Vim and *++ff=dos* will convert the file with dos file format. Now your file is read as a Windows file and all `^M` disappeared

```
:e ++ff=dos
```

Now use *:set ff=unix* to convert the file to Unix format.

```
:set ff=unix
```

Finally do *:wq* to save and exit.

```
:wq
```

If you'll like to know more ways to fix this problem check them out in here: [Convert between Unix and Windows text files](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux#:%7E:text=To%20input%20the%20%5EM%20character,dos%20to%20convert%20to%20Windows.)